# Get request headers from node-proxy to R- Shiny

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, auth0, shiny-server

I am authenticating a user using Auth0 and have a node server working as a proxy server. The authenticated user is redirected to my shiny app. I want to access/parse the node request header in R to get the user data. How do I pass my request header details from node to a shiny server.

I tried accessing it using Sys.env(). But it doesn't have the user details( probably because I am not able to get it from node server).